# Check instance variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't understand how I must change an `if (condition)` to check for the presence of this variable.

```
<%= if (@article.location != nil) %>
<%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@article.location.latitude}%2C#{@article.location.longitude}" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `@article` has a `location` method, one typically uses the `present?` method for this purpose:

```
<% if @article.location.present? %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

You can substitute `nil?` if you want to be more strict about it (`present?` returns `false` for an empty string, which is usually what you want).

If you're not sure that `@article` even has a `location` method, you can test for it first, using `respond_to?`:

```
<% if @article.respond_to?(:location) && @article.location.present? %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: oh great, really helpful, can you add documentation about all like_this? methods

Comment: They all come from different places. `nil?` and `respond_to?` are part of core ruby. `present?` is part of ActiveSupport. There are many such meta methods.